# Is there a way to symbolically represent the random sum of a random variable?

Tags: python, statistics, sympy

Say I have some random distret random variable N, and some other random variable X. I want to make a new compund random variable Y as follows.

```
Y = \sum_{i=1}^{N} X_{i}
```

where X_i are independent and identically distributed random variables from the same distribution as X.
(Sorry for the code block, I have too low rep to post pictures.)

So codewise I'd begin with somethine like

```py
from sympy import abc, stats, S
N = stats.Geometric(name='N', p=S.One/2)
X = stats.Normal(name='X')
```

or whatever distributions I was interested in for the discrete and summand random variable. I've been looking at the docs and examples, but can't find a way to represent the compund variable I'm interested in. Then be able to invoke `stats.E(Y)` or `stats.variance(Y)`.

I know I can calculate conditional expected values and variances along with other computations to calculate the "total" expected value and "total" variance. I can do that on my own, but I'd like to verify that work with a direct symbolic construction then invoke.

Answer (score 0):

Until you stick to the normal distribution, like in your example, the sum is the same normal random variable, which E and var you may need to sweat to get to, given the discrete random variable is exotic. But if you deviate from normal, ooh-la-la, the things will become very nasty real quick. Monte Carlo is often the only solution. In the place of sympy developers, I would stay away from this mess.

Comment: Well, at least with E[Y], no matter what distribution you have for X and so long as N is always discrete, then E[Y]=E[N] E[X] (presuming X and N are independent). So I was hoping that could be consistently done with symbolic computation.

Comment: E[Y]? People will want standard deviation, cdf, pdf, quantile function - everything they expect from some standard distribution. And won't get it.

Comment: Fair. Though I suspect that in the specific case of the discrete sum of a random variable should be possible. I wonder if specific compositions could be done.